# how can I start Internet Explorer 10 always in kiosk-mode?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I 'll use a win7 computer as an information terminal. After its startup internet explorer is starting up in kiosk mode with the wanted side. The use of hotkeys like windows button, ctrl c etc is disabled. When I click for further information on this page (which isn't created by myself) the browser starts a new window and the whole ie-menu is available.
How can I setup this browser, that every ie-window is starting up in kiosk mode?

Comment: So the page the kiosk is pointing at has a link that is causing a pop-up that has all the browser controls available in it?  Perhaps use a pop-up blocker, or better, don't use a standard browser?

Comment: @fepi: How are you disabling hotkeys? I don't think kiosk mode does this itself.

Comment: I 've found a usefull link which explains how to do it, but it's in German http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBvYy7D3hZk

Comment: @fepi: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

- Firstly, run the Group Policy Editor by clicking the Start button and
  choosing **Run...** or pressing <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and typing `gpedit.msc` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- In the left hand pane go to **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer**
- Find the entry **Enforce full-screen mode** and double-click it
- Set it to **Enabled** and click the **OK** button

[image: Group Policy Editor]

Note that users can still open new windows but they will lack all menus etc.

Also I would say that the security of such a system still isn't great. If your users have access to a keyboard and mouse connected to the machine then they might still be able to bypass your efforts to secure it.

Answer (score 1):

To start IE in kiosk mode, run `iexplore.exe -k "C:\path\to\\webpage.html"`

From [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154780/how-to-use-kiosk-mode-in-microsoft-internet-explorer):

> To start Internet Explorer in Kiosk mode, click **Start**, click **Run**, type the following command in the **Open** box, and then click **OK**
>
> iexplore -k **page**
>
> where **page** is the Web page address for the Web page that you want to appear when Internet Explorer starts. If you do not specify a Web page in the **Open** box, Internet Explorer opens your start page. Note that the Web page that you specify can be a Web page on the Internet, on your computer, or on another computer on the network.